# Accessing guest (Ubuntu) localhost from host (Windows)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, localhost

Is there any way to access guest's localhost through a browser inside the host? I am running Ubuntu with Virtualbox on Win7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on how your guest is connected to network.

If you are connecting through `NAT`, virtualbox provides port forwarding. Your access against `host:port1` will be mapped to `guest:port2` then. This is my preferred way.

Or if you are using `Bridge`, just check IP address of guest, and use it in host's browser.

Answer (score 1):

Get your guest's ip address using `ifconfig`.

Type this ip address on your host browser's address bar.

Comment: or http://localhost

Comment: Localhost won't work since it's aim the local machine. If you type localhost on Win7 you're going to reach your Win7 machine. Host and guest are different machines with different IP addresses.